# Javascript simple class scope changes when button is pushed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this is one of the basic questions. I am creating a custom Javascript class and using Jquery on top to do few things. After checking if document is ready I am calling init() and adding event handler. However, when I click the button, I get inside "turnLightOn" function but when it tries to call another function for this class the scope of this has changed to the "button" so I get

```
Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'getDataFromServer'
```

I know this is a simple question but can anyone point to the right answer for me?

```
<div id="cp">
    <ul>
 <li><button id="light_switch">Light On</button></li>

    </ul>
</div>    

<div id="room"> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var CP = function(widget, light_switch){
    this.widget_name = widget;
    this.light_switch = light_switch;
    var self = this;
    console.log(this);
};
CP.prototype.init = function(){ 
    $("#"+this.light_switch).on('click', this.turnlighton);     
};
CP.prototype.somecallback = function(){
    console.log(this);
};
CP.prototype.turnlighton = function(){
    this.getDataFromServer(somecallback);
};
CP.prototype.getDataFromServer = function(callback){
    $.ajax({url:"/"+fname,
            success:function(result){
                 callback(result);
          }
    });
};    

$( document ).ready(function(){
        var c = new CP("control_panel", "light_switch");
        c.init();
    }   
);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the click handler `this` by default will refer the clicked element, you can pass a custom context by using [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
$("#" + this.light_switch).on('click', $.proxy(this.turnlighton, this));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8aD9U/)

Comment: this worked. so, this is because of the special context that "this" keyword has. Is there a better way to approach this than using the proxy or bind? Actually can you give example with bind?

Comment: @user1647708 in the given scenario I'm not seeing another way, but for just showing another way using a closure variable - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8aD9U/4/

Comment: thanks for the demo. Do you see the necessity of needing two "var self" then in this scope?

Comment: thanks again for the help. If i can ask another question for this same problem. When i do "turnlighton" i hit ajax function and then i want to do a callback function for this. i do the callback but the scope of this is outside the object. How do I bind the scope of this callback to my object?

Comment: @user1647708 you can pass a option called `context: this` to the ajax like `$.ajax({
    url: "/" + fname,
    context: this,
    success: function (result) {
        callback(result);
    }
});`

Comment: That didnt quite work. the callback does get called but the scope has shifted to "Window" - Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…} when i  did console.log(this) inside the callback function.

Comment: @user1647708 sorry you need to use `callback.call(this, result)`... I missed out that you were calling `callback()`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

```
$("#"+this.light_switch).on('click', this.turnlighton);
```

In this above code this.turnlighton will taken current this of on() method in jquery. you use CP function this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _this;
var CP = function(widget, light_switch){
    this.widget_name = widget;
    this.light_switch = light_switch;
    _this = this;
    console.log(this);
};
CP.prototype.init = function(){ 
    $("#"+_this.light_switch).on('click', _this.turnlighton);     
};
CP.prototype.turnlighton = function(){
    console.log(this);
    _this.getDataFromServer();
};
CP.prototype.getDataFromServer = function(){
    /*$.ajax({url:"/"+fname,success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }});*/
};    

$( document ).ready(function(){
        var c = new CP("control_panel", "light_switch");
        c.init();
    }   
);  
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VCEL/)

Comment: won't work because `self` is not defined in the scope of `init`

Comment: Now i edited the scenario please replace the init function in your code